# Javascript on page load?

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```
var myarray=[(lots of things)];
var elem=document.getElementById('subtitle');
window.setInterval(function(){
    elem.innerHTML=myarray[Math.round((myarray.length-1)*Math.random())];
},30000);
```

This works fine, except for the first 30 seconds, nothing happens. I have to wait until it reruns for anything to happen. Can I make it choose one from `myarray` on page load? Thanks

Comment: `window.onload` event... Google... Euh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to wait for 30 seconds because when you set a interval, it does not fire it right away! Break it out into a function and call it. If you add the script after the element on the page, you do not have to worry about window.onload or document ready.

```
<div id="subtitle"></div>
<script>
    (function(){
        var myarray=[(lots of things)];
        var elem=document.getElementById('subtitle');

        function dispNum() {
            elem.innerHTML=myarray[Math.round((myarray.length-1)*Math.random())];
            window.setTimeout(dispNum,30000);
        }    
        dispNum();
    })();
</script>
```

reunning example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUBBG/)

Comment: Are you 100% absolutely positively sure that every page load will take exactly 30 seconds?

Comment: @H2CO3, the poster is saying it is not running until 30 seconds. They never call it when the page starts.